# R Raster error: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Tags: r, gis, rgdal

Trying to pull in and scale a Landsat image but receive an error, this seems to be a somewhat common issue given the older questions and various ways of creating a RasterLayer object.

After loading the libraries I need I get to this and hit an issue:

```
    Directory <- "D:/Geo Files/LANDSAT"
prefix <- "CU_LC08.001_"
suffix <- "_doy2020222_aid0001.tif"  


## Get band 2 reflectance (blue, 0.45-0.515 micron)
sr2 <- raster(paste0(Directory,prefix,"SRB2",suffix))
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

*Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)*
> sr2 = sr2*0.0001 #Scale
Error: object 'sr2' not found
```

The full name of the first (SRB2) file I want to use is:
CU_LC08.001_SRB2_doy2020222_aid0001.tif - the name of the file as it's downloaded, unchanged.

The rest of the code continues through the other files to go through each SRB and later calculate NDVI, etc

i.e.  `## Get band 3 reflectance (green, 0.533-0.590 micron) sr3 <- raster(paste0(Directory,prefix,"SRB3",suffix)) sr3 = sr3*0.0001 #Scale`

Edit 1: I tried using try using \ instead of forward slashes and got exactly the same error.
R version is R-4.0.3

Any help would be appreciated, this was provided to us in a hackathon and I am new to R, it should be simple to run but if the file cannot be read..?

EDIT 2: The issue was with the end of the path, it needed "\"

```
Directory <- "D:\\Geo Files\\LANDSAT\\"
```

But when trying to get another file to work from a different folder later in the code, the same issue appears, and the above fix did nothing:

```
 Directory <- "D:\\Geo Files\\ECOSTRESS\\USCities\\"
LST_ECO <- raster(paste0(Directory,"SDS_LST_doy2020260040819_aid0001.tif"))
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

EDIT 3: Changed \Geo Files\ to "\GeoFiles\" as suggested, tried again but problem still occurs as above.

Comment: Windows paths can cause issues. Maybe try using `\\\` instead of forward slashes.

Comment: @geotheory I tried this and it gave the same error as above. I will add it this to my question.

Comment: Can you do a `file.exists(paste0(Directory,prefix,"SRB2",suffix))` to see if you can even reach that path without those libraries? Also, what version of R are you using?

Comment: @onlyphantom That returned "false". R version is R-4.0.3

Comment: Would changing Geo Files to GeoFiles on your OS be possible? R doesnt place nicely with spaces in the path (supposedly fixed after R 3.5 but worth a try). Then modify the string `Directory <- "D:/GeoFiles/LANDSAT"`

Comment: Try `list.files()` and see what it shows..

Comment: Suggest navigate to the folder (e.g. `setwd()` ), then put double quotes in the console and press tab once or twice until you see the available files, and select the relevant file. The correct string will then appear in the console.

Comment: @onlyphantom Done. Issue still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and the following was the process that finally worked.

```
# location of the file
loc_1 = "D:\\Geo Files\\ECOSTRESS\\USCities\\SDS_LST_doy2020260040819_aid0001.tif"

# check if the file can be read into r
tif1 = readr::read_file(loc_1)
```

It raised the following error (edited):

```
Error: Cannot read file "D:\\Geo Files\\ECOSTRESS\\USCities\\SDS_LST_doy2020260040819_aid0001.tif": The cloud file provider is not running.
```

The reason was because R could not read the file as it was in an online folder.

Confirm if the file is available offline. If it can be read by `read_file` function then the `raster` function should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
i was loading a raster file from my local storage
I added ".tif" extension to the name of the file and it worked